# Error ng-options en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy consumiendo un Ws el cual me devuelve un array, y a éste lo presento en un select, los datos se  muestran bien pero quiero saber como le doy un valor por defecto esto es lo que he realizado

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Categoría 1:</label>
  <select class="form-control" 
   ng-init = "data.emp_cat_uno = categorias[0]" //no funciona
   ng-options="c.nombre_cat as c.nombre_cat for c in categorias "
   ng-model="data.emp_cat_uno"
   ng-change = "setear_id_cat_1()">
  </select>
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.hideLoader = FctLoader.show($scope.hideLoader);
ServCategorias.servicioCategorias().success(function(data, status){
   $scope.categorias = data.data.categorias;
})
.error(function(data, status){
   alert(status+' provinicias');
})
.finally(function() {
  $scope.hideLoader = true;         
});
```

service

```
.service('ServCategorias',['$http',function($http){
    this.servicioCategorias = function(){
        return $http.get('url');
    };
}])
```

Quiero saber como hago que el primer valor este por defecto espero y haya solucion con todo les agradezco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste lo siguiente:

```
$scope.hideLoader = FctLoader.show($scope.hideLoader);
ServCategorias.servicioCategorias().success(function(data, status){
   $scope.categorias = data.data.categorias;
   $scope.data.emp_categoria_uno = data.data.categorias[0].nombre_cat; // Agregar esto
})
.error(function(data, status){
   alert(status+' provinicias');
})
.finally(function() {
  $scope.hideLoader = true;         
});
```

O en el html:

```
 ng-init = "data.emp_cat_uno = categorias[0].nombre_cat"
```

Puede ser que no seleccione la primera o un valor por default, porque en el ng-for, el value del option es el `nombre_cat`, entonces cuando asignas todo el objeto completo al ng-model (ng-model="data.emp_cat_uno" = categorias[0] => objeto completo, no solo el nombre), no lo puede encontrar.

Espero que funcione, cualquier cosa, podemos hacer una prueba en un plunker con un objeto similar al que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio de esta manera $scope.data.emp_cat_uno = $scope.categorias[0]; desde mi controller

Comment: Buenísimo! Saludos